# Questions about the Perceptron convergence proof

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, machine-learning

I have some amateur questions about the perceptron convergence proof:

1. I don't understand where we got $k\gamma$ from, specifically how did we go from $\frac{\theta^{k-1}\theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}+\gamma$ to $k\gamma$?
2. How did we go from $\|\theta^{k-1}+y^{(i)}x^{(i)}\|^2$ to $\|\theta^{k-1}\|^2+2y^{(i)}\theta^{(k-1)} x^{(i)}+\|x^{(i)}\|^2$?

   Since $\| \theta^{k-1}+y^{(i)}x^{(i)} \|$ is just an expression of this vector's length, I would have thought that the $\| \|$ and the square would have cancelled each other out, thus leaving us with only $(\theta^{k-1})^2+(y^{(i)}x^{(i)})^2$?

   (As far as I understand, the length of a vector $(x,y)$ is just $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$)

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can view it from the perspective of mathematical induction.

We have $$\frac{\theta^{(1)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}\ge \frac{\theta^{(0)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}  + \gamma = \frac{0\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}  + \gamma=\gamma$$
and  hence by induction hypothesis
$$\frac{\theta^{(k)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}\ge \frac{\theta^{(k-1)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}  + \gamma \ge (k-1)\gamma   + \gamma=k\gamma$$

2. For real number $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$. For real vector, $\|a+b\|^2=\langle a+b, a+b\rangle=\|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2\langle a, b \rangle.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I understand 2) now, but I am still having difficulty understanding 1)...it's not apparent to me that we are doing induction here, so $\frac{\theta^{(1)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|}\ge\gamma$ is presumably the base case, but what's the statement we are trying to prove (in particular, what's the induction hypothesis?)

Comment: Statement: $\forall n \ge 1, \frac{\theta^{(n)}\cdot \theta^*}{\|\theta^*\|} \ge n \gamma$. Assume it's true for $n=k-1$ and now you want to prove the statement for $n=k$.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it, as soon as the statement is made clear everything just clicked, thank you so much!